# Choosing priors for the parameters of Gamma distribution

Tags: bayesian, prior, gamma-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ is a sample drawn from a Gamma distribution with parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then, the likelihood function can be written as follows:
\begin{equation}
L(\mathbf{x}|\alpha, \beta) = \frac{\beta^{n\alpha}}{\Gamma^n(\alpha)}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i^{\alpha-1}\Big)\exp\{-\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\}
\end{equation}
I aim to obtain the posterior distributions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ under the assumption that we consider independent priors for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. In other words, we want to find
\begin{equation}
L(\alpha| \mathbf{x}, \beta)\propto L(\mathbf{x}|\alpha, \beta) \times L(\alpha)\\
L(\beta| \mathbf{x}, \alpha)\propto L(\mathbf{x}|\alpha, \beta) \times L(\beta)
\end{equation}
I want to know which kind of prior we can consider for parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that we can derive a known posterior distribution for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. A regular choice may be Conjugate priors, but seems to be difficult to guess.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no conjugate prior to the gamma distribution that takes $\alpha$ independent of $\beta$ *a priori*. There is however a non-independent prior here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Bayesian_inference

Alternatively, if you _must_ assume independence, use any indpendent prior you see fit and use software such as Stan or JAGS to implement an MCMC sampler to obtain draws from the posterior.

Comment: So, only in case, we consider a joint prior for parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we can find a posterior. For the second way, I need mathematical proof rather than a software implementation. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: Do you think considering non-informative priors is suitable? I need to generate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in a Gibbs sampling by their corresponding posterior distribution. That is why I need a separate distribution for each parameter.

Comment: *I might be wrong* assuming independent gamma priors over $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would allow for gibbs sampling

Comment: Ok, if we use the conjugate prior in the Wikipedia link, then it is possible to find a posterior estimation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by Gibbs sampling method?

Comment: You can use Gibbs sampling if the full conditional distributions ($L(\alpha \mid x, \beta)$  and $L(\beta \mid x, \alpha)$) are known, easy to sample from probability distributions. Sometimes this property is called "semi-conjugacy".  My guess is that this holds for your use case

Comment: Since we can obtain the joint prior for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, is it possible to have $L(\alpha| x, \beta)$ or $L(\beta| x, \alpha)$. It seems that we need to find the marginal prior as well, which is my main question.